# live-server can't find the file specified

Tags: npm, npm-live-server

I'm trying to setup a reactjs project and using live-server. My project structure -

```
fa/
-node-modules/
    ...
-public/
    bundle.js
    index.html   
-src/
    app.js
package.json
```

My package.json file -

```
{
  "name": "fa",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "watchify src/app.js -o public/bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ react es2015 ] ]",
    "server": "cd public; live-server --port=1234 --entry-file=index.html"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "live-server": "^1.1.0",
    "watchify": "^3.7.0"
  }

}
```

I ran on one cmd "npm run build", then "npm run server" on another. It gives errors-

```
17 error Windows_NT 6.2.9200
18 error argv "E:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "server"
19 error node v6.6.0
20 error npm  v3.10.3`enter code here`
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error fa@1.0.0 server: `cd public; live-server --port=1234 --entry-file=index.html`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the fa@1.0.0 server script 'cd public; live-server --port=1234 --entry-file=index.html'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the fa package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     cd public; live-server --port=1234 --entry-file=index.html
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs fa
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls fa
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Faced the same problem. Change the following:

```
 "server": "cd public; live-server --port=1234 --entry-file=index.html"
```

to this:

```
 "server": "live-server --port=1234 --open=public --entry-file=index.html"
```

For some reason, it is not processing `cd public`

**More reference:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server

Answer (score 9):

I know this question already has been answered for long time ago.

**Real answer** are change the following:

```
"server": "cd public; live-server --port=1234 --entry-file=index.html"
```

**to this**

```
"server": "cd public & live-server --port=1234 --entry-file=index.html"
```

Just put `&`

Answer (score 1):

I use `live-server --port=1234 --open=public --entry-file=index.html` in the command line
and it works for me.